# Projecting points in a complex plane to the image coordinates plane

Tags: complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, transformation

I have points in a complex plane defined by `-1.8 <= Re(x) <= 1.8, -1.8i <= Im(y) <= 1.8i`. I want to map these points to an image plane ( (0, 0) top left, (1000, 1000) bottom right). What sort of transformation must I perform?